# PDFMerger table of contents lost after merging files

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I have a pdf that I generated with wkhtmltopdf (also generates a table of contents with links) and another pdf that I use as a cover. I merge the two pdfs using PDFMerger (a php library). After this merge, the table of content is not clickable no more, any ideas on how I could solve this issue?

Comment: Have you looked at the source of the resulting pdf?

Comment: Please provide more details on what is not working and what the result is afterwards.